# extjs form submit rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, form-submit

i am working with Ext JS form submission with Rails as backend..
Everything works fine when i use Chrome i.e. values get inserted into the database, but when i use any oher browser for my appn i.e. IE or Mozilla, form values dont get inserted into database.. What can be the reason?? Am i missing something??
I get an alert "submitted" in IE & Mozilla,but i guess its not reaching controller(url) of my rails appn...Following is the code :

`var sbtn=Ext.getCmp('submitbtn');
        sbtn.on('click',function(){
            var frm=Ext.getCmp('FormPanel');
            frm.el.unmask();
           frm.getForm().submit(
            url = '/customers/new',
            alert('Submitted'),
            window.open('customers.json')
            );`

Comment: Please put your solution in Answer section & mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found solution to my own problem.. its working in IE/Mozilla now..I just realized i need to add the attribute **standardSubmit: true** to my FormPanel component.